# Prove that $\Bbb C[x,y]/\langle xy-1\rangle]\cong\Bbb C[s,t]/\langle s^2+t^2-1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

To prove that $Spec(\Bbb C[x,y]/\langle xy-1\rangle)\cong Spec(\Bbb C[s,t]/\langle s^2+t^2-1\rangle)$, Yoneda's lemma says we need to prove that $\Bbb C[x,y]/\langle xy-1\rangle]\cong\Bbb C[s,t]/\langle s^2+t^2-1\rangle$. Looking at the units, I think we may define $x\mapsto s+it,y\mapsto s-it$. But so far I haven't came up with a way to formally prove that it is indeed an isomorphism: I cannot directly prove that it is a bijction, since I haven't got the basis. And I also thought about the first isomorphism theorem...but have no idea about it.

Could someone please help to explain a formal way to show that they are isomorphic? Thanks.

Comment: Often, proving something is an isomorphism is best done directly, by write down the inverse homomorphism and proving it is the inverse. In my opinion, even in those settings where every bijective homomorphism is an isomorphism and every isomorphism is bijective, the approaches by showing a homomorphism is bijective is much less useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to show that your map has an inverse.  So you could define
\begin{align*}
\psi: \frac{\mathbb{C}[s,t]}{\langle s^2 + t^2 - 1 \rangle} &\to \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle xy - 1 \rangle}\\
s &\mapsto \frac{x+y}{2}\\
t &\mapsto \frac{x-y}{2i}
\end{align*}
and show that $\psi$ and your map are mutually inverse.

Comment: Should not this be interpreted as isomorphism between variety $A^1-\{pt\}$ and variety $A^1-\{pt'\}$ by simple coordinate transformation of the second one, where $pt$ is just a point? Then this isomorphism is obvious.

Comment: @user45765: One must first show that these two varieties are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1 - \{ * \}$. Doing so would be a fine answer to the exercise that prompted this question. (but not to the question of "What do I need to do to turn the argument I already came up with into a proof?")

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes. I just thought pictorially it is clear and one can write down the morphism from this picture which is much straight forward to solve it. It was my bad habit that I will abandon the idea when I cannot see something as intuitive. It was a bad habit from physics.

Comment: @user45765 Sure, you're right that one could think about this more geometrically.  Over $\mathbb{C}$ every conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, and since both of these conics intersect the line at infinity in two distinct points, then both are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ minus a point.